# error in creating new file in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[image: error in creating a new notebook.]

I am getting an error in creating a new jupyter notebook. I am attaching a picture of the error. can anyone help me  to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hello , Please read this first [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) this reference may [help](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8997) you

Comment: Thanks. I am new on the site, will take care in future and not upload image of the code/error.